# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, build, code-signing

When I am building my project, I am getting this error:

> CodeSign "build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app"
>   cd /Users/crackers/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp
>   setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>   /usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx (D492H27WDR)" "--resource-rules=/Users/crackers/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/Users/crackers/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp/build/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyApp.xcent" "/Users/crackers/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app"
>
> /Users/crackers/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

I have both Xcode3.x and Xcode4.x (iOS5 beta) installed in my mac.
Few week ago everything was working fine. All certificates was working fine.
All certificates are in good state.

I had moved the Xcode(s) files to new directory. After that I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you moved the Xcode files to a new directory and you get this error after you did that, then obviously you should reinstall Xcode in the proper Developer location which is the default. Im running the iOS 5 Beta Xcode and it works fine in the proper directory. First completely uninstall Xcode following a tutorial from the web like this: http://macdevelopertips.com/xcode/how-to-uninstall-xcode.html

Then reinstall Xcode in the proper place, let me know if this works. IMHO it should work though.

Comment: I have installed xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final in /Developer and xcode_4.2_and_ios_sdk_5_beta_6 in /Developer4. Is it creating problem ?

Comment: Yea it probably is. Delete both completely and install your main Xcode in the developer folder and it should work then.

Comment: Also if this solves your issue, feel free to accept the answer and up vote it!

Comment: yeah sure, I will uninstall all Xcodes, then I will install only one xcode. Let me check it, then I will confirm you. Thanks :)

Comment: I have not tried it yet.... :( Need to finish some important works in my projects.